# Different results for CPE search on NVD

Tags: vulnerability, cve, nist

I usually stick to finding the right CPE candidate for product-version I am interested in by using the [Search Vulnerability Database](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search) with `Search Type` selected as `Advanced` and then narrowing down from `Vendor` to `Product` to specific `Version`. Lets call it *MyMethod*.

Recently I was interested to finding CVEs that applies to `HP-UX B.11.31`. I applied the above mentioned process and ended up with [33 matching records](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search/results?isCpeNameSearch=false&cpe_vendor=cpe%3A%2F%3Ahp&cpe_version=cpe%3A%2F%3Ahp%3Ahp-ux%3Ab.11.31&cpe_product=cpe%3A%2F%3Ahp%3Ahp-ux&results_type=overview&form_type=Advanced&search_type=all&startIndex=20).

Although a simple Google query gave me CVEs that were not listed in above 33 results. In order to understand what was happening I researched more and found [CPE Search](https://nvd.nist.gov/products/cpe/search) utility within NVD. Querying this with just `B.11.31` gave me [two candidates](https://nvd.nist.gov/products/cpe/search/results?namingFormat=2.2&keyword=B.11.31). The second CPE `cpe:2.3:o:hp:hp-ux:b.11.31:*:*:*:*:*:*:*` seemed right one for me which gave [80 matching records](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search/results?isCpeNameSearch=true&query=cpe%3A2.3%3Ao%3Ahp%3Ahp-ux%3Ab.11.31%3A*%3A*%3A*%3A*%3A*%3A*%3A*&results_type=overview&form_type=Advanced&startIndex=60).

Comparing the CVEs from both the searches, I found that all 33 listed in MyMethod are present in these 80 results.
Comparing the CPEs, they are almost similar `cpe:/:hp:hp-ux:b.11.31` `cpe:2.3:o:hp:hp-ux:b.11.31:*:*:*:*:*:*:*`

Going through the CPE specification documents, it appears that the `o` in second CPE represents `operating system` which makes sense. Although it is still confusing as far as my understanding goes. Given that the *MyMethod* builds a more generic CPE and should have more inclusive results from values such as `a/o/h` and but its the other way around.

I failed to find detailed guides on use of CPEs. I am doubting that MyMethod is erroneous. In my method I manually selected the right products and yet it is still missing out on valid results that applies to the product I am searching for. I am not sure what is happening in the two cases.